# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n+n}{n^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n+n}{n^2+1}}$$

I know that we can say that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n+n}{n^2+1}}\approx \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} {\frac{2}{\sqrt[n]{n^2}}}=2$$

Is there another way?

Comment: You can make it more rigorous with squeeze theorem:$$\frac{2^n}{2n^2}<\frac{2^n+n}{n^2+1}<\frac{2\cdot2^n}{n^2}$$There is also ratio implies root:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$provided the left limit exists.

Comment: It's fine !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach is good, although $\approx$ is a bit vague.

You can also use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n+n}{n^2+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2^n+n}{n^2+1}\right)^\frac1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\log\left(\frac{2^n+n}{n^2+1}\right)}n\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

By using the squeeze theorem:
It is $2^n+n\leq n^22^n+2^n$ so you get that your limit is $\leq2$. On the other hand, $2^n+n\geq2^n$ and it is $(n^2+1)^{1/n}\to1$, hence your limits is $\geq2$.